# How to upload and run jmeter script from server

Tags: jmeter

There is a need to upload the script from local to server and then run over there. can someone please let me know how to can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy it from local machine to the "server" using [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) for Linux or [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) for Windows, once done you can log into the server over [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) or [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) and execute your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

---

If you want fully unattended/automated execution consider the following:

1. Setting up a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), i.e. use [Github](https://github.com/) to store your script(s)
2. Configure the [Webhook](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) to trigger an action when you commit the file
3. Install [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) on the server
4. Configure [Jenkins to listen to the Github Webhook](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline) and when it happens kick off a build running a JMeter test

This way whenever you add new or update existing script it will automatically trigger the job which will execute the test, check out [How to Integrate Your GitHub Repository to Your Jenkins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project) article for detailed steps if needed.